# Why does the python interpreter prompt with ... for a comment "#"?

Tags: python, comments, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

In the Python interpreter, if I put in a `#` for a comment, why does it prompt with `...`?  I expected a `>>>` prompt.

e.g.,

```
>>> # my comment
... x = 4
>>> x
4

>>> # my comment
... foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: It's expecting a statement. It's skipping the comment and prompting for the rest of the statement (hence `...`). Much like if the command contains a line continuation or an unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: I think the better question to ask here is why are you trying to enter comments using a commandline?

Comment: if it is an issue why not put your comments after, `foo = 4 # foobar`

Comment: I think a good question is *why* would the interpreter expect a statement. Likely, it's just an artifact of how the REPL parses the input, and it wasn't worth optimizing this special case.

Comment: You can turn the question on its head and ask, "why when I just press <enter> **doesn't** the interpreter prompt with `...`?" [My best guess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25755478/20789) is that totally blank lines are special-cased into the interactive interpreter, while whitespace/comment-only lines are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my *educated guess* about what is going on; I haven't actually looked at Python's [REPL](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) code. As you know, the Python interactive shell uses the `...` prompt when it is expecting further input based on having parsed the contents of the preceding line(s).

For example:

```
>>> if True:
...
```

... because `if ... :<newline>` must be followed by an indented block according to the [lexical structure of Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

Notice that you can trigger the same slightly odd behavior with a line that is empty except for whitespace, e.g.:

```
>>> <space><enter>
...
```

According to the lexical rules of Python, in most contexts a line that contains only whitespace should not be treated as a `pass` statement, or an empty block, but it should be handled **as if it didn't appear at all**. Take this example (with `|` to emphasize the lack of whitespace at the end of each line):

```
if False:|
|
    print "Foo"|
# comment|
    print "Bar"|
|
print "Baz"|
```

If you run this code, it will print only `Baz`. The first two `print` statements are treated as part of the same block **despite the fact that there are non-indented empty or comment-only lines before, after, and in the middle of them**.

Basically, when the Python interpreter reads a line that is blank or contains only a comment, it pretends it didn't read any line at all. The interactive interpreter basically follows this behavior: it's waiting for input, and if it gets no input, it asks for more input. Hence the `...` continued input prompt.

It appears that the case of a **totally blank** line (`line==''` after chopping off the EOL character(s)) is special-cased into the interactive interpreter, but that this special-casing is not extended to lines which contain only comments and/or whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

It is the prompt, just like when you type in `def foo () :` and press enter, it puts an ellipsis (...) and with some prompts automatically tabs for you. It's just it's way of saying that it is accepting that you are doing something over multiple lines.

Comment: "doing something over multiple lines" -- but in the case of "#", it is a single-line "operator".